# Select Vert under move gizmo

Tags: modeling

If I have the move gizmo on it restricts me from selecting a vertex that is below one of its axis lines. Also if I have a vertex selected and I want to drag around another vertex then it is interpreted as a move on the vertex that is selected.

I checked the preferences but could not find anything that would do the trick.

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either rotate the view so the vert is easily selected, or you can disable the gizmo while you select the vert.

In 2.79 the shortcut is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> or you can turn it on/off in the header.

[image: gizmo options]

In 2.80 the shortcut is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> and is also available in the header.

[image: gizmo options in 2.80]

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was hoping for a preference setting that I missed which allows the select of verts under the gizmo. The workflow is a bit of a pain either using g or leaving the move gizmo in place. Either way its more clicks, which I was hoping to avoid. thanks again